# Nginx conflicts static files when serving multiple React apps in same domin using docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

This is my nginx configuration

```
server{
    listen 4000;
    server_name localhost;
    
    location / { 
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/stg;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;       
        
    }   
    location /marketing {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/web;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }   
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
    - "4000:4000"
    - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./new-build/:/usr/share/nginx/html/web/
    - ./stg/:/usr/share/nginx/html/stg/
```

path / is load the static data
but the path /marketing is  can't serve the static files
is there any other configuration i have to do?

I have two react projects in the same domin with diffrent path
like path / loads the main app and path /marketing loads the admin app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add sup project inside the main project folder

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
    - "4000:4000"
    - "4001:4001"
    - "4002:4002"
    - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./new-build/:/html/dashboard/
    - ./build-path-app/:/html/dashboard/app/

server{

    listen 4000;
    #this will take a main project folder static
    root /html/dashboard;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    #this will take a static folder under the sup project
    location ~ ^/app/((?!(static|(.*\..*))).)+$ {
        try_files /app/index.html =404;
    }

}
```